Generate a list of monthly dates for a year in Snowflake
I am trying to generate a list of dates for a batch process.  I want to create the dates a month apart, for a year.  So, I have my last load date of 24-03-2018, so I want to create a list of dates 23-04-2018, 23-05-2018 etc for a year.  I have a bunch of tables, each with a potentially different low date.
Ive tried to do a recursion, but snowflake doesnt seem to have a max recursion option, so I cant get it to work properly:
Thank you in advance for any help
WITH RECURSIVE dates_cte AS (
    -- start date
    SELECT SF_LOWDATE ::DATE as dt
    ,replace(replace(object_name, '[',''), ']','') AS object_name
    FROM table_sf_lowdates
    UNION ALL
     SELECT   DATEADD('month',1,dt) as dt,  object_name
    FROM dates_cte
  --  dont go past a year
    WHERE dt < DATEADD('year', 1, dt)
)
SELECT * FROM dates_cte   order by  dt;


This should give you what you want:
select add_months('2018-03-24',seq4()+1)::date
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 12))
;


I notice the OP mentions 24th of the month and then says they want a sequence around 23rd (presumably day before). I've upvoted anyway. This answer is near enough! The OP can refine it from there if required I'm sure.
